# Using Bootstrap with Meteor and React

Tags: reactjs, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can not find a clear way to use Bootstrap with Meteor-React combination. There are a number of packages in Atmosphere which expected to exposure global variable with consequent references to Bootstrap functionality, but after, for example,

```
meteor add universe:react-bootstrap
import BS from 'bootstrap';
```

system complaints that 'bootstrap' is not defined.

What I did now, I included CDNs for Bootstrap nd jQuery directly into my client's `main.html`, and got it working:

```
render() {
        return (
            <li>
                {this.props.ad.text}
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Star
                </button>
            </li>
        );
    }
```

But it is not seems a good solution. jQuery is included in Meteor app by default, how to reference it? When I tried to add twbs:bootstrap package, it is also not clear how to include it in html. Simply added, it does not work.

Comment: importing symbols from Meteor packages is done via `import { somevar } from 'meteor/<packageName>';`.

Comment: I was confused by Atmosphere's packages like universe:react-bootstrap. Seems they are simply not supported and old. Thanx to Khang, solution is:
`meteor npm install --save react-bootstrap`
and then use it like:
`import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';`
`<Button>Left</Button>`

Answer (score 0):

To use React with Bootstrap, you should use this module [react-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap). It has been out there for sometimes and seems still good. I use it for some of my Meteor React projects, I have nothing to complain till now.